# I want a function when dismiss SecondViewController finish

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit, uiviewcontroller, dismiss, viewcontroller

I need help with my code on Cocoa Touch (for iOS/iPhone).
I want a function when dismiss SecondViewController finish, because I need to pass one string to from second view controller to first view controller.

When I include First View Controller in Second View Controller, the debugger return this:

"Expected specifier-qualifier-list before `FirstViewController`"

Thanks for all and sorry for my english.
Lucas Moreira.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the compiler saying that, not the debugger. (Notice that it's in the Build Results window. Since you did not complete the build, your code has not run yet; when you do get it to run, it will run under the debugger. Messages from the debugger, and from your running app, appear in the Debugger Console window.)

> ```
> Expected specifier-qualifier-list before FirstViewController
> ```

That's a syntax error. Your code is syntactically invalid; the compiler cannot understand it.

You should probably change your compiler to clang in your Xcode build settings, as clang has better error messages than the default GCC compiler. If you still can't make sense of the problem, edit your question to include your code for the function or method that the compiler doesn't like.

At a guess, either you forgot a semicolon on the line before the one the compiler pointed to, or you forgot to put the function or method body in braces (`{}`).

Comment: This happens when I include the FirstViewController in SecondViewController, I think this happen because the SecondViewController is included on FirstViewController (the FirstViewController includ yourself again). Can you understand? If no, I can upload my code.

Comment: Yes. Either you're importing the implementation (.m) instead of the header (.h), or you have a cyclical-import problem. Maybe both. Use `@class` directives in the headers, and import the headers in the implementation files.

Comment: Do you a tutorial? I don't understand how to do.

Comment: You should only ever import headers (.h files), not implementation files (.m files), and headers should generally import nothing. The most common exception is that a header for a class should import the header for its superclass. For any other classes that the header needs to refer to, use a `@class` directive in the header to tell the compiler that those names are names of classes, and import those classes' own headers in the implementation file. See http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocDefiningClasses.html .